# Go App Engine - Testing Memcache service failures

Tags: google-app-engine, testing, go

I am trying to test the failure paths in my Go GAE application. I am testing using the included `appengine/aetest` package that creates a `dev_appserver.py` subprocess to handle API calls, however it seems impossible to tell the API stub to start failing (it always works).

A promising thing I tried was using [withmock](https://github.com/qur/withmock) to actually mock out the memcache package and make the functions return the series of errors I'd like. Alas I found `withmock` is not very compatible with App Engine.

Comment: Ah, I'm not using Go on GAE, and/so I'm not at all sure I know the right way. (It does sound like withmock would be nice.) Worst case, you could always restructure your program a bit so you can stub the cache out: for example, write a `cache` package that defines a `type Cache interface {...}` and `func New(c appengine.Context) Cache` that can return a `MemCache` object that just proxies all calls to the memcache module or a `FakeCache` that fails in the way you want for tests.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good feature request. Please file one over on the App Engine issue tracker!